# Help inequality involving exponential function

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that $e^{x} \geq \left (1 + \frac{x}{n} \right) ^{n}$ holds for each non-negative real $x$ and each integer $n \geq 1$ ? I tried series and induction but got stuck. Can you please help?

Comment: Hint :  use, $\exp(y) \geq 1 + y$ for all $y$.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT** $\ $ Consider $\rm\ e^z\ \ge\ 1 + z,\ \ z\ =\ x/n $